# Extracting metadata from mp4 to excel

Tags: csv, video, metadata, extract, mp4

I have hundreds (and **hundreds**) of 20-30s videos from camera traps (for wildlife monitoring) that at present we are going through one at a time and extracting the metadata by hand. This is incredibly slow and I know there must be a better way to do this but my colleagues are confident that no such tool exists for mp4's.

All I need from the video files is date, time and video length (in seconds) in an excel compatible format.

There are a number of programmes out there (review: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/ece3.4464) but I've not been able to surmount the tech savvyness required to simply extract a few pieces of metadata. I'm an ecologist not a software developer! (Said Dr. Bones never).

I have found many how to's on extracting image metadata or audio using Exiftool but none for videos. I am also not a coder (other than dappling in R) and exiftool looks pretty intimidating. Similarly other options like TRAPPER (https://gitlab.com/oscf/trapper-project) may as well be in Greek.

**TL:DR**
How can a non-coder/IT person extract date, time and video length from hundreds of videos into a csv file?

Answer (score 0):

Using [ExifTool](http://exiftool.org) your command would be along these lines
`exiftool -csv -CreateDate -Duration# /path/to/files >/path/to/Output.csv`

This command will take the embedded create date and the duration of the video and create a CSV file which Excel will then be able to load.

Normally exiftool will display the duration in a more human readable form (hours:minutes:seconds) but the hashtag at the end tells exiftool to list the raw value of the `Duration`, which will be in seconds.

Comment: If you have any questions, feel free to come over to the [exiftool forums](https://exiftool.org/forum) where the author is quite responsive to questions.